# How do you debug without an interactive console

Tags: python, debugging

As a self-taught programmer, I learned to debug using an interactive console that kept all of my variables in memory when I build /run the script.  However, I noticed the overwhelming trend for debugging in IDEs (and, I suppose CLI + Editor solutions, for that matter) is to build your script in one place and provide a separate console "sandbox" type area that only keeps variables if you copy/paste your code.

How do you debug without an interactive console?  Can anyone list a few debugging steps that could help me be a better programmer / debugger?

Currently, this is a very simplified version of what I do:

1. Write some pseudocode (sometimes)
2. Write some code in an editor that *should* work
3. run / build the script
4. Check stdout for errors
5. If no errors, then 7.
6. If errors, then back to 2 after fixing the offending code.
7. Type variable names into console to verify that they look like I
   anticipated.
8. Rinse and Repeat until it works as I intended.

Comment: "if no errors, then 7" ?

Comment: @jh314 That answers a different question I had about how to run python scripts from within python.  I now feel like a moron for not having heard of pdb, so your comment is extremely helpful.  Thanks.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The best way to do this would be to [write tests](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3371255/writing-unit-tests-in-python-how-do-i-start). That automates steps 3 through 7 for you. It also prevents regressions from occurring when you change other code.

Answer (score 1):

you can use the `q` module for this easily https://pypi.python.org/pypi/q

**xyxy.py**

```
import q
do_something()
q.d() #this will open interactive shell

def f():
    do_something()
    q.d() #open console here with access to all local variables of f
```

you can also use automated tests (builtin unittest module or nosetests or something else)

Answer (score 1):

Use a decent python IDE - there are a lot out there and you will be able to stop at breakpoints inspect variables by hovering or adding watches and enter a context console where you can interact with your code in the context of the breakpoint.

Comment: I actually got in StackOverflow trouble for asking the IDE question [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18025529/is-there-a-python-ide-that-keeps-variables-in-memory?noredirect=1#comment26364918_18025529).  Pycharm and many others do this like I am used to, but I'm picking up that it's not the *best* way to code.

Comment: Which is best is a matter of opinion hence not a __good__ question - the _best_ way to code is to know it all and get it right first time.  Doesn't happen that often to most of us.

Answer (score 1):

Use print statements in between the areas of problem code... otherwise, just download a good IDE

Comment: Increasingly, this is the answer I'm comfortable with.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that PyCharm, at least, DOES have an interactive console and the default keymapping (on Mac) is option-shift-E.  Then your variables are loaded in memory.  However, the suggestions above are better programming practices.