# How can I use monkey patching in Python to replace a specific argument?

Tags: python, monkeypatching

I want to use monkey patching to change all statements such as `time.sleep(5)` to `myServer.sleep(5)`. How can I realize it? Thank you very much!

```
import test
import subprocess
import ast
import os
import time
import sys

if __name__ == "__main__":

    def insomniac(duration):
        pass  # don't sleep

    _original_sleep = time.sleep
    time.sleep = insomniac

    def dont_write(stuff):
        pass  # don't write

    _original_write = sys.stdout.write
    sys.stdout.write = dont_write

    execfile("test.py")

    exit(0)
```

Comment: Monkey-patching should not be your first resort. What goal are you trying to achieve by replacing these statements?

Comment: What programming language are you using?... Python?

Comment: I want to test the original codes so don't want the time.sleep to waste time.

Comment: yes, it's Python...I'm really a young young beginner

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your focus is on testing, i.e. you want to ensure that a callable in some external library out of your control is called in a specific way, there are testing libraries that can help you with this, such as [`mock`](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/mock).  It can be pretty involving to set all those things up correctly so when I do coding I typically try to structure my code in a way that minimizes the usage of mocks.

Take a look at the [documentation for `mock`](http://www.voidspace.org.uk/python/mock/) if you really want to get your toes wet towards this direction.  While at this, you probably should formalize your testing techniques to make use of [`unitttest`](http://docs.python.org/library/unittest.html).  If you are lost, [Writing unit tests in Python: How do I start?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3371255/writing-unit-tests-in-python-how-do-i-start).