# Writing a test in python

Tags: python, python-3.x

Im currently taking a python class and im new in programming. I have written the code below and want to write a code that tests if the ResilientPlayer actually does what it is supposed to. The code is from a chutes and ladders board game where the ResilientPlayer is a "special" type of player that gets a "superpower" in its next move afther falling down a chute. The next round afther he has fallen down a chute, he will add a given or a default number to the die_roll, and I want to test if my code actually does this! Hope someone can help me with this problem :)

```
class Player:
    def __init__(self, board):
        self.board = board
        self.position = 0
        self.n_steps = 0

    def move(self):
        die_roll = random.randint(1, 6)
        self.position = self.get_position() + die_roll

        self.board.position_adjustment(self.position)

        self.n_steps += 1

    def get_position(self):
        return self.position

    def get_steps(self):
        return self.n_steps


class ResilientPlayer(Player):
    default_extra_steps = 1

    def __init__(self, board, extra_steps=None):
        super().__init__(board)
        self.extra_steps = extra_steps
        if self.extra_steps is None:
            self.extra_steps = self.default_extra_steps

    def move(self):
        if self.get_position() in self.board.chutes.values():
            die_roll = random.randint(1, 6)
            self.position = self.get_position() + die_roll + self.extra_steps

            self.board.position_adjustment(self.position)

            self.n_steps += 1
        else:
            super().move()

    def get_position(self):
        return self.position

    def get_steps(self):
        return self.n_steps
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Writing unit tests in Python: How do I start?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3371255/writing-unit-tests-in-python-how-do-i-start)

Answer (score 1):

The best way to do this is using the unittest class, I do this as following:

```
import unittest
from .... import ResilientPlayer


class TestResilientPlayer(unittest.TestCase):

    def setUp(self):
        self.resilient_player = ResilientPlayer(....)

    def test_move(self):
        # Do stuff
        self.assertEqual(1, 1)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    unittest.main()
```

Here, `unittest.main()` will run all the tests in the file. `setUp` is run before each test (so you can have multiple tests with the same starting conditions).

This is an incredible useful module and I strongly suggest reading more on it, check [the documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.html)

Comment: Thank you! Like I said, im really new in programming, so I struggle to see if this tests what i want.. You are positive that this test cheks that the ResilientPlayer actually adds given or default number to the die_roll the round afther falling down a chute? :)

Thank you for your tips about the module, i will definetly read more about that one!

Comment: @ErikRullestad this code doesn't really do anything at the moment, it's just a basic set up that allows you to write tests :)